# ngDialog confirm multiple click

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

Via ngDialog popup window I am collecting data to a $scope array. If a user clicks confirm button multiple times, data will be added multiple times. I have tried ngDisable by $scope variable to disable the the button but unfortunately ngDialog  popup window does not pick up scope changes until confirm function is completed.
https://jsfiddle.net/lasith011/11cdp05c/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngDialog']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, ngDialog) {
        $scope.names = [];
    $scope.openDialog = function(){
        ngDialog.open({
        scope: $scope,
        template: 'templateForm',
        closeByDocument: false,
        controller: 'PopUpController'
      });
    }
});
myApp.controller('PopUpController', function($scope, ngDialog, $timeout){
    $scope.cancel = function(){
    ngDialog.close();
  };
  $scope.submit = function(){
    $scope.disable = true;
    //Some calculation
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.names.push($scope.varName);
      ngDialog.close();
    }, 1000);   
    $scope.disable = false;
  };
});
```

Comment: share your code @lasith

Comment: @LokeshKumarGaurav sorry for the delay https://jsfiddle.net/lasith011/11cdp05c/

Answer (score 0):

Why you add a $timeout with 1000 milliseconds? Remove it should be ok enough.

```
myApp.controller('PopUpController', function($scope, ngDialog){
    $scope.cancel = function(){
        $scope.closeThisDialog();
    };
    $scope.submit = function(){
        $scope.disable = true;
        //Some calculation
        $scope.names.push($scope.varName);
        $scope.closeThisDialog('cancel');
        $scope.disable = false;
    };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/3spbjpt8/